# working with RDDS and collections in Scala

Tags: scala, rdd

I have the below function that takes an array of means of type Likes (`type Likes=Int`)
and an RDD of numbers of type Likes (likesVector). For each number in the likesVector RDD, it computes the distance from each mean in means array and chooses the mean which has the least distance (`val distance = (mean-number).abs`). While I expect a result of type `Map[Likes,Array[Likes]]`, I get an empty map. `Map[Likes,Array[Likes]]` represents `(mean->Array of number-nearest numbers)`.
What is the best way to achieve this? I suspect it has a lot to do with the mutability of Scala collections.

```
def assignDataPoints(means:Array[Likes],likesVector:RDD[Likes]): Map[Likes,Array[Likes]] ={         
        var likes_Mean = IntMap(1->1)
        var likes_mean_final = mutable.Map.empty[Likes,Array[Likes]]
        likesVector.map(dataPoint => {
          means.foldLeft(Array.empty[Likes])( (accumulator, mean)=> {
            val dist= computeDistance(dataPoint,mean)
            val nearestMean = if (dist < accumulator(0)) {
              accumulator(0)=dist
              accumulator(0)
            } else{
              accumulator(0)
            }
            val b= IntMap(nearestMean.toInt -> dataPoint)
            println("b:"+ b)
            likes_mean_final ++ likes_Mean.intersectionWith(b,(_, av, bv: Likes) => Array(av, bv))
            accumulator
          })})        
        likes_mean_final.toMap
      }
```

Comment: I don't understand the context of your operations. Can you update your questions with some inputs and outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your empty map is that you are using `++` operation here in the line:

```
likes_mean_final ++ likes_Mean.intersectionWith(b,(_, av, bv: Likes) => Array(av, bv))
```

`++` operation returns a new map hence we are creating a new object and not changes the current value

The operation for mutating the current mutable map is `++=`. So you should use:

```
likes_mean_final ++= likes_Mean.intersectionWith(b,(_, av, bv: Likes) => Array(av, bv))
```

Also no need to use `var` in your context as you are not reassigning values to the same references.

But you should not use mutability in Scala.